# Golang: Broadcast messages to websocket when a particular POST JSON is received

Tags: rest, post, go, websocket, broadcast

I have an app that is connected to my goserver using websocket . I used this code to create a websocket connection - https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/chat

```
http.HandleFunc("/ws", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        serveWs(hub, w, r)
    })
```

When I receive a POST call I need to broadcast a message - "Order Received: " productNum to all the devices. productNum is received in the post request.

```
http.HandleFunc("/post",BroadcastMessage())
```

I want to know what I need to write in BroadcastMessage() to do this. Please help.

Comment: I have written written the code to parse json and I have the productNum variable. I just need to broadcast the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In BroadcastMessage, send a `[]byte` to the hub's broadcast channel:

```
 hub.broadcast <- message
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works like a charm!